# Can not overwrite folder from source to destination

Tags: bash, cp

Hello i am trying to overwrite a folder ***publish*** from a `source` to a `destination` with the following shell script:

**update.sh**

```
src= './Server/Core/Server/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/publish'
dest= './Server/publish'
echo  "Src:${src},Dest:${dest}"
cp  "$src" "$dest"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
$ ./update.sh
./update.sh: line 1: ./Server/Core/Server/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/publish: Is a directory
./update.sh: line 2: ./Server/publish: Is a directory
Src:,Dest:
cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
```

Why can't it parse the `src` and the `dest` ? I have tried with both `"$src"`and `"${src}"` to no avail.

Comment: Your copy won't work for directories. Your variable assignment has extra leading spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove spaces in variable assignment.
also, for copying with subdirectories use "`cp -r`" to copy directories recursively

execute "`cp --help`" for other options

Answer (score 3):

Remove the whitespace before first quotation mark, no whitespaces should exists before or after `=`.

Variables should be declared like this:

```
src='./Server/Core/Server/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/publish'
dest='./Server/publish'
```

with the whitespace before quotation mark it considers the paths to be files that need to be executed, and result of those commands, if the files existed, would be value of the variable.

Similar if you added whitespace before `=`, it would consider variable name to be a command that needs to be executed.

From bash man pages

> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
>
> name=[value]

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. You should firstly, add a header to your bash script
2. Then your variable assignment is incorrect (extra spaces)
3. Your cp is not copying any eventual subdirectories

Working example:

```
#!/bin/bash

src="./src/data"
dest="./dst/data"
echo  "Src:${src},Dest:${dest}"
rm -rf ${dest}
cp -R ${src} ${dest}
```